# How can I install Node Js in xfce/ Debian based linux Distros?

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, npm-install

How can I install Node Js  & npm in Xfce/Debian based linux distros.
Please help me.

Comment: Give nvm a go, I use it to install node.js on anything... (I run node on windows, debian and RaspberryPi OS (debian based)
Install multiple versions and switch with a single command
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md

Comment: ^^^ The answers that were last revised after 2020 are more up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Here is the solution :
Step 1: Download latest or recommended node .tar.xz file from https://nodejs.org/en/

or you can download node version 14.15.5 (.tar.xz file) directly from here ->

https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.15.5/node-v14.15.5-linux-x64.tar.xz

Step 2: Go to the directory in which (.tar.xz file) is downloaded.

In my case --> /Download directory

Step 3: Update System Repositories

**sudo apt update**

Step 4: Install the package xz-utils

**sudo apt install xz-utils**

Step 5: To Extract the .tar.xz file

**sudo tar -xvf name_of_file**

In my case --> **sudo tar -xvf node-v14.15.5-linux-x64.tar.xz**

Step 6: **sudo cp -r directory_name/{bin,include,lib,share} /usr/**

In my case --> **sudo cp -r node-v14.15.5-linux-x64/{bin,include,lib,share} /usr/**

Step 7: Check the node version

**node --version**

Result In my case -> v14.15.5